# Is there an available build demonstrating new JDK 7 features?

Tags: java, java-7

I wish to test the new features that will came with the next JDK like project coin, project lambda etc. but the last JDK 7 to download will not have any already implemented!

From which build can I test them?

I think it's incredible that, now in may 2010 at few months to the official final release (november 2010????) for we developers there is no possibility to test any of this features!!

Comment: Just because you couldn't find it doesn't mean it doesn't exist. In fact just Googling for `JDK7` returns the base URL Pascal is linkin to in his answer. IDE support is still rather basic though.

Comment: Do you have downloaded it and test before answer me?  I think no! In fact before post my question I've downloaded the last build (b94) and try to see if some features have been implemented. But no features, I ask for, have been already implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [CAP program](http://java.sun.com/cap/index.jsp).  In addition to the early release builds available for download via the normal download channels, you can also access the weekly snapshot builds.

You'll need to sign an Non-Disclosure Agreement though ...

**EDIT**

From browsing some messages in the [lambda-dev mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/), I get the impression that the implementation of closures in Java 7 may be suffering from "resourcing issues", and the (now) Oracle technical folks are not allowed to talk about it.  That may explain why closures support is not showing up in the builds yet.  If you signed up for CAP, you *might* be able to find out more.  (And before you ask, no I haven't signed up and I don't have any inside information.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get OpenJDK 7 / JDK 7 binary snapshot releases from http://download.java.net/jdk7/binaries/.

Comment: No, sorry, also the last b92 doesn't contain any new features implemented: no project coin, no closure etc.